# iOS dynamic height cell in tableview- issue with row 0 and 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, height

I am having a tableview in which I am displaying my data. As you can assume from the title, these cells are dynamic in their content, and so should their height be. Actually I got it working, but I have a strange issue with the row 0 and 7. These 2 rows take my entire screen, but when I scroll past them and go back again everything is fine. I am not sure but the 7. cell must be among the first cells that are being "dequed" when I scroll down. But as I said, this is just the first time they are being displayed, when I scroll again to one of them, everything is looking good (when filling the tableview with new data it is also fine).

I tried to reload the tableview twice when it is being populated for the first time, but without success. The presentation of the first cell I have fixed calling : `self.tableView reloadAtIndexPaths ...` when the table is being populated for the first time,
and it worked, it has the height it should have regarding its size. But I still have the issue with cell number 7 (the above fix does not work for this cell, I assume because it is not being displayed at that moment)
I am not using any fancy height calulation, just the iOS 8 feature:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
```

Is there a method, fix with which i can force the tableview to draw the cells again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cell size is calculated from constrains. So I assume there is something wrong with those or with data during computation.

try this:
in tableview cell subclass use -prepareForReuse method to clean cell data as before reuse.

Comment: and when setting the constraints "right" (although I got everything blue and all views have a left,right, top and bottom constraint) autolayout calculates the right height for every situation ? (landscape, portrait, rotation ...) I have some situations where I have 2 labels in the same row, and both can vary in their sizes. I assume that I have to play with the hugging and ressistance values, but until now I dint't figure out the right values. Is there any tutorial, or explanation on that ?